# What is the difference between adding a module dependency, Library, and Global Library when using shared jars between modules in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I currently have the jars included as a dependency on each module, but this seems redundant. Is there a difference between the three methods and the respective use cased?

As far as I can tell, the only place that specifies jars or directories is when adding a module dependency. When adding a library or global library I can select Java, Maven, or Kotlin/JS. Since I'm not using Maven or Kotlin that leaves Java. Would I still use that option even with a third party library, i.e. Apache Poi?

Also is there a standard location for jar files used in the project? Currently the jars are located in a common location outside of the project. When I run the tomcat server and attempt to use the jars in the webpage I am getting a "Cannot create temporary file" error in the location of the jar. I know this is due to the location being write protected, but I have the same setup in eclipse without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global library is available for all the projects, you add it once and reuse in other projects and modules.

Project library can be used if you have multiple modules in the same project that need this library so that you don't have to define it in every module. Updating the library contents in one place is easier than in every module.

Module dependency is used if the library is needed only in this specific module.

Technically there is no difference, all the libraries present in the module dependencies are just added to the classpath.

If you are not using Maven/Gradle/Ivy/SBT in a project, you may want to store the jars inside the project, for example in the `lib` directory.

To use the jars in the web application they must be also [included into the artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html) that you are deploying on the server.

Comment: Thank you. That cleared it up a lot. Especially the part about global libraries, I thought it was restricted to the project or window. Eclipse must handle the libraries differently. I just place them in the tomcat installation and they are automagically imported and available.

Comment: Just don't forget than any library including the global library must be still added to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies) if you want the code in this module to access the classes in the library.